# The errors when installing Brotli for Apache

Tags: apache, brotli

I followed this [example](https://www.tunetheweb.com/performance/brotli/) to install Brotli for Apache (2.4.58 with RHEL 7.2).

```
sudo yum install wget
sudo yum install perl
sudo yum install gcc
sudo yum install pcre-devel
sudo yum install cmake.x86_64   

cd ~
mkdir sources
cd sources

git clone https://github.com/google/brotli.git
cd brotli/
git checkout v1.0
mkdir out && cd out
../configure-cmake
```

When I ran to `../configure-cmake`, it threw an error:

```
-bash: ../configure-cmake: No such file or directory
```

I've tried searching for any solutions to the error but got nothing.
Then I got stuck.

I don't know how to continue, can anyone help me?

---

Edit:
According to the official [example](https://github.com/google/brotli?tab=readme-ov-file#cmake), I tried the `cmake` way.

Just continuing from where I was stuck:

```
$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=./installed ..
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:4 (cmake_minimum_required):
  CMake 3.15 or higher is required.  You are running version 2.8.12.2
```

So I checked the version of `cmake`:

```
$ cmake --version 
cmake version 2.8.12.2
```

I tried `sudo yum install cmake` to install a newer version, but the version that appeared was still `2.8.12`. So I removed it and installed `cmake3`.

Remove `cmake 2.8.12.2`:

```
$ sudo yum remove cmake
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
...............
Remove  1 Package

Installed size: 20 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
...............
Removed:
  cmake.x86_64 0:2.8.12.2-4.25.amzn1                                                          

Complete!
```

Check if it is deleted:

```
$ cmake --version
-bash: /usr/bin/cmake: No such file or directory
```

Install `cmake3`:

```
$ sudo yum install cmake3
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
--> Running transaction check
...............
Installed:
  cmake3.x86_64 0:3.17.5-1.3.amzn1                                                                      

Dependency Installed:
  cmake3-data.noarch 0:3.17.5-1.3.amzn1                                                     

Complete!
```

Check if it is installed:

```
$ cmake --version
-bash: /usr/bin/cmake: No such file or directory
```

So, the command must be changed to `cmake3` from now on:

```
$ cmake3 --version
cmake3 version 3.17.5
$ whereis cmake3
cmake3: /usr/bin/cmake3 /usr/lib64/cmake3 /usr/share/cmake3
```

Okay, go back to where I was stuck:

```
$ cmake3 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=./installed ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Build type is 'Release'
-- Performing Test BROTLI_EMSCRIPTEN
-- Performing Test BROTLI_EMSCRIPTEN - Failed
-- Compiler is not EMSCRIPTEN
-- Looking for log2
-- Looking for log2 - not found
-- Looking for log2
-- Looking for log2 - found
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/ec2-user/brotli

$ cmake3 --build . --config Release --target install
Error: could not load cache
```

I searched for this error but got no help, the free space of the disk is about 30GB.
Does anyone have any suggestions?